# Attaching meta-information to an object in .NET

Tags: .net

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't find the original(s).

I am getting some objects that I need to "attach" some information to. Basically, if that object ever gets back to the same piece of code, I need to see that I have seen it before.

ie. something like this:

```
Dictionary<WeakReference<ObjectType>, string> _Cache;
```

Note the weak reference in there (I know WeakReference is not generic btw), I need to make the key of the cache a weak reference, to handle the fact that the objects are GC'ed out of my control.

Now, I can make that cache full of weak references, but I seem to recall a similar type of system already existing in .NET, which was GC'ed automatically alongside the object.

Note that I do not recall the overhead of this, so I will make sure to read up on the subject before deciding if this is a good/better solution than my own cache. Unfortunately I cannot change the object in question, so I need to keep track of this meta-information somewhere else.

My limitations:

- The object is not mine, so I cannot change it in any way possible
- I cannot inherit from the object, as it is sealed, besides, I'm *given* the objects, I do not construct them, so I would have to be able to replace an instance with a new object of a descendant type for this to be useful
- The objects are GC'ed out of my control, so I cannot just use a dictionary, which will slowly fill up, either with "references" to nonexistant objects, or will hold on to the objects, I would need a dictionary with a weak referenced key (thus: custom dictionary)
- The objects, although I could encapsulate them within my own code and thus carry alongside it the required information, is passed back to a framework out of my control, and given back to me from the same, and thus I need to be able to retrieve/look up the old information with just the object in question

Basically, something like:

```
PropertyAttacher.Attach(instance, "Name", name);
```

Do I remember correctly? What are the classes involved?

Comment: That question is not relevant here, although the problem seems similar, the accepted answer here mentions using an attribute, or altering the type (or descending from it), neither of which I can do.

Comment: What about ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) ?

Comment: @Simon Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. If you leave it as an answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: Though the type is for .NET 4.0 and I need something for 3.5, but this was what I was remembering, so the answer is spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for .NET 4's [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx)

Comment: Yep, that was it, though it is for .NET 4.0, and I need something for 3.5, this was what I was remembering.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can build a dictionnary indexed by [RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx).

**From MSDN:**

> RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode is useful in scenarios where you care about
>   object identity. Two strings with identical contents will return
>   different values for RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode, because they are
>   different string objects, although their contents are the same.

EDIT:
@Simon Mourier's solution seems to be a much better one.

Comment: I've thought about this, but this would mean that I either store weak references to the objects, alongside the hashcodes, in order to detect that the objects have been collected, or I risk the dictionary just growing without bounds. For the moment I will let this part of the problem wait, since we're slated for upgrading our project to .NET 4.0 in the near future.